# Exception handling advice for an array with nulls or undefined in some of the arrays in the response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I am running into an error : `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` that is being caused by the section of my code dealing with the hourly performance.

`EDIT PROBLEM FOUND | NO SOLUTION YET`

I tried wrapping each of the lines individually in a try catch and an IF null logic. I found that the reason I have some undefined values is that because one reporting set is for the current day. There is a report with non existent arrays for that time series that hasn't yet elapsed. I am not sure how to treat those right now other than attempting to exclude that particular report or run the report on days where we have not sent. I would love help on that solution.

`END EDIT`

The problematic section is below and is intended to extract the values from a multi level array (item 2 from the 2nd level array) from the response. Documentation on the [Mailchimp Response here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/reports/). I think I must be winding up with a null or undefined value in this section of the final array, so when I attempt to print to the spreadsheet I am getting a conversion error

```
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 0] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  1st hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 1] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  2nd hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 2] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  3rd hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 3] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  4th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 4] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  5th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 5] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  6th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 6] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  7th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 7] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  8th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 8] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens  9th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[ 9] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 10th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[10] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 11th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[11] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 12th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[12] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 13th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[13] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 14th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[14] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 15th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[15] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 16th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[16] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 17th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[17] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 18th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[18] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 19th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[19] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 20th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[20] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 21th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[21] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 22th hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[22] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US'),  // Opens 23rd hour
Object.values( Object.values(el.timeseries)[23] )[2] .toLocaleString('en-US')  // Opens 24th hour
```

Full code minus API token:

```
***********************************************************************************
 * Current Iteration and most up to date
 * 
 * API call for top level metrics on all emails for Mailchimp Emails performance.
 * 
 * *********************************************************************************
 */

function mailChimpApiReports() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(" Calling the Mailchimp API. This may take a minute!", "‍ Process Started", -1);

  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
      "Authorization": "Bearer {API TOKEN} "
    } //enter credentials of Basic Auth (if required)

  };

  try {
    // call the API
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports?count=10", params);
    var data = response.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    // Logger.log(data)
    // Logger.log(json)

    // get data array
    var arrayData = json['reports']; // replace '<value>' with the name of your 1st-level array

    // blank array to hold the data for Sheet
    var arrayProperties = [];

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("I've gotten a response from the monks . Just a few moments while I crunch the numbers.", "Monkeying around...", -1);

    // Add the arrayProperties to the array
    arrayData.forEach(

      function(el) {

        arrayProperties.push( //Object.values(
          [
            'https://us18.admin.mailchimp.com/reports/summary?id=' + el.id,
            'https://us18.admin.mailchimp.com/reports/clicks?id=' + el.id,
            el.id,
            el.subject_line,
            el.send_time.slice(0, 10),
            el.campaign_title,
            el.emails_sent.toLocaleString('en-US'),
            el.abuse_reports.toLocaleString('en-US'),
            el.unsubscribed.toLocaleString('en-US'),
            Object.values(el.bounces)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), //forwards_count
            Object.values(el.bounces)[1].toLocaleString('en-US'), //forwards_opened

            Object.values(el.bounces)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), //hard bounces
            Object.values(el.bounces)[1].toLocaleString('en-US'), //soft bounces


            // "opens":{
            // "opens_total":121575,
            // "unique_opens":94402,
            // "open_rate":0.4848014872408498,
            // "last_open":"2022-07-13T23:31:06+00:00"
            // },
            Object.values(el.opens)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), // total opens
            Object.values(el.opens)[1].toLocaleString('en-US'), // unique opens
            (Object.values(el.opens)[2] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // open rate


            // "clicks":{
            // "clicks_total":14537,
            // "unique_clicks":12402,
            // "unique_subscriber_clicks":8884,
            // "click_rate":0.04562378352839675,
            // "last_click":"2022-07-13T23:30:37+00:00"
            // },
            Object.values(el.clicks)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), // total clicks
            Object.values(el.clicks)[1].toLocaleString('en-US'), // unique clicks
            Object.values(el.clicks)[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // unique subscriber Clicks
            (Object.values(el.clicks)[3] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // click rate

            // "facebook_likes":{
            // "recipient_likes":0,
            // "unique_likes":0,
            // "facebook_likes":0
            // },
            Object.values(el.facebook_likes)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), // recipient likes
            Object.values(el.facebook_likes)[1].toLocaleString('en-US'), // unique likes
            Object.values(el.facebook_likes)[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // FB likes

            // "industry_stats":{
            // "type":"Media and Publishing",
            // "open_rate":0.1869852617085266,
            // "click_rate":0.029609050108562393,
            // "bounce_rate":0.004072030686123725,
            // "unopen_rate":0.8089427076053497,
            // "unsub_rate":0.000716032666115744,
            // "abuse_rate":4.118661798843233e-5
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[1] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // open rate
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[2] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // click rate
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[3] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // bounce rate
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[4] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // unopen rate
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[5] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // unsub rate
            (Object.values(el.industry_stats)[6] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%', // abuse rate

            // "ecommerce":{
            // "total_orders":0,
            // "total_spent":0,
            // "total_revenue":0,
            // "currency_code":"USD"
            Object.values(el.ecommerce)[0].toLocaleString('en-US'), // total_orders
            Object.values(el.ecommerce)[1].toLocaleString("en-US", {
              style: "currency",
              currency: "USD"
            }), // total_spent
            Object.values(el.ecommerce)[2].toLocaleString("en-US", {
              style: "currency",
              currency: "USD"
            }), // total_revenue

            // Object.values(el.tracking)[5],
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[0])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  1st hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[1])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  2nd hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[2])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  3rd hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[3])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  4th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[4])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  5th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[5])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  6th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[6])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  7th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[7])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  8th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[8])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens  9th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[9])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 10th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[10])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 11th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[11])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 12th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[12])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 13th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[13])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 14th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[14])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 15th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[15])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 16th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[16])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 17th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[17])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 18th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[18])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 19th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[19])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 20th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[20])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 21th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[21])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 22th hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[22])[2].toLocaleString('en-US'), // Opens 23rd hour
            Object.values(Object.values(el.timeseries)[23])[2].toLocaleString('en-US') // Opens 24th hour


          ]
        );






      });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Recording the results and formatting dates.", " Almost Done!", -1);



    Logger.log('arr prop ' + arrayProperties);


    var flattend = arrayProperties.flat(-1);

    Logger.log('flat! ' + flattend);


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Import'); // replace 'Sheet1' with the name of your Sheet

    // calculate the number of rows and columns needed
    var numRows = arrayProperties.length;
    var numCols = arrayProperties[0].length;

    // output the numbers to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(flattend);

    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1);

    dateFormat();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Give yourself a pat on the back. Not bad for a primate. ", "✅ We're done! ", -1);

  } catch (error) {
    // deal with any errors
    Logger.log(error);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Seems like there was a problem. Give it a few moments and Try again.", " Uh oh!", -1);

  };

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. Usually there are two options whenever you get null or undefined instead a real data: 1) skip the step, 2) replace the data with dummy (or empty) data. JS has the special syntax: `var a = b || c` which means if 'b' is undefined: a = c.

Comment: Hi there @GasWizard! Please test the approach explained by @YuriKhristich. If that doesn't help, could you please clarify the line that generates the error?